# Debouncing fixed scroll with trackpad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First of all thanks in advance for helping me out.

So I have this website I am trying to make with a custom scroll behavior. The functionality in firefox and chrome in a pc with a mouse is great, the problem resides when using a laptop with a trackpad, specifically a macbook.

Here is a fiddle with the code I have : https://jsfiddle.net/0pn7byo9/

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    attachFixScroll();
    var scrolling = false;
    var keys = {32: 1, 33: 1, 34: 1, 35: 1, 36: 1, 37: 1, 38: 1, 39: 1, 40: 1};

    function attachFixScroll() {
        var div = document.getElementById("div1");
        div.addEventListener('mousewheel', preventDefault);
        div.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault);
        document.onkeydown  = preventDefaultForScrollKeys;
    }

    // left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40,
    // spacebar: 32, pageup: 33, pagedown: 34, end: 35, home: 36


function preventDefault(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.preventDefault)
        e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = false;  
    //Call fix scroll
    if ( !scrolling )
        debounce(fixScroll(e), 1000);
}

function preventDefaultForScrollKeys(e) {
    if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
        preventDefault(e);
        return false;
    }
}


function fixScroll(e){
    if ( !scrolling ){
        scrolling = true;

        var h = $("#div2").height();
        var scrollDirection = e.wheelDelta || -e.detail;
        console.log('scrolling');
        if(scrollDirection < 0){
            $('#div1').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#div1").scrollTop() + h
            }, 400, function() { scrolling = false;  });
        } else {

            $('#div1').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#div1").scrollTop() - h
            }, 400, function() { scrolling = false;  });
        }
    }

}


   function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this,
            args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if ( !immediate ) {
                func.apply(context, args);
            }
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait || 200);
        if ( callNow ) { 
            func.apply(context, args);
        }
      };
    }

    });
```

I already tried debouncing but Idk why it doesnt work, the only thing it kind of work was using a timeout to turn back the boolean "scrolling" once the animation finished, but I had to wait 1 second that is really not smooth at all, and it didnt worked well in firefox (macbook).

So what should I do for this to work on a macbook and dont need to wait 1 second to able to scroll again. like this website : http://dwarfplanet.co